# How to write Kafka RestProxy Server/Client for production use

Tags: scala, rest, apache-kafka

Need to develop a rest API which can read published messages from kafka cluster to a dataware house application.

Materials available over internet say use POST/GET commands , but i don't think this is for production use rather useful for testing purposes.

How to implement it in scala/ Java Programming?

Comment: "Need to develop a rest API " … "how to implement it in scala/ Java Programming "…… can you explain *what* you're trying to build?

Comment: My reason for asking *what* over *why* is that if you're trying to get data from Kafka into a data warehouse the standard way to do this is with Kafka Connect, which is neither of the things you asked about.

Comment: @suman gorantal you will have to tell us the specific problem we can't write the whole end point for you. so please add some code which has some problem or some other problem etc.

Comment: I need to publish data avaialble in kafka cluster to a data ware house application using REST PROXY Interface or rest API

Answer (score 0):

> Materials available over internet say use POST/GET commands , but i don't think this is for production use rather useful for testing purposes

Please link to where you read this... All production web-services operate over (more than) these two HTTP methods, hundreds of thousands times a day...

If you want to really use Kafka for throughput, though, you wouldn't "hide it" behind a REST interface, though. You would distribute SSL certs plus usernames+passwords, to remote clients, for example.

> Need to develop a rest API which can read publish messages from kafka

REST is not meant to keep an open connection, primarily because it is stateless (it shouldn't maintain where you are reading from in Kafka)... It would make more sense to forward a websocket from a Kafka consumer, which is different from a REST API.

> how to implement it in scala/ Java Programming

The Confluent REST Proxy is already written in Java, and it is open-source (and used in Production at several companies, I believe). If you need inspiration, then you can start there. Otherwise, you can find examples of Spring and Vert.x, for example, with their Kafka integrations in their respective documentations, but you'll be re-implementing a lot of the existing functionality.